# Best way to update an item in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I show feed items using RecyclerView and on clicking that item i take user to another activity which shows feed in details.

In another activity user can do some operations which changes that particular feed. When user press back button to come back to RecyclerView, then item doesn't show updated data.

To tackle this I pass a reference of the RecyclerView's item to next Activity and call update on that reference which eventually updates the feed in RecyclerView's item.

Is this the right way to do it or there's better way?

Comment: are you using `sqlite` for local database for feed?

Comment: No, i don't use sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send a message to your recylerview adapter. just check this library; [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

create a Model for data transferring

```
public class YourModel {

int id;
String updateValue;


public YourModel(int id, String value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.updateValue = value;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
}

 public String getValue() {
    return updateValue;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
     this.updateValue = value;
}

}
```

main activity;

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(YourModel model) {
    int updateIndex = model.getId();
    String newValue = model.getValue();
    arraylist.set(updateIndex, newValue);
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(updateIndex);
}
```

and for your detail activitiy

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new YourModel(yourItemPosition, yourNewUpdates));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Don't know why it didn't clicked earlier. I do have my own library that works on observer pattern. Thanks :)